# Difference between "get down here" and "come down here"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

Could someone please tell me the difference between "get down here" and "come down here"? Is "get down here" even natural or is it bad English?

Comment: **Get down here** is what you might say to an naughty child who has defied you by climbing a tree. **Come down here** is what you might say to a friend whom you wish to show something special. The first is an instruction; the second an invitation - depending on your tone of voice.

Comment: I agree with Ronald Sole. But if they are used in a different context, like "When can you _get down here?_" and "When can you _come down here?_", they are almost identical. "Get down here" may sound slightly American to the most refined of English ears.

Answer (score 2):

“Come over here” is just slightly on the “polite” side, while “get over here” is just slightly on the “rude” side.

The difference between them is not very large, and you could probably make “get over here” sound somewhat polite by saying “please” and using a gentle tone of voice. Likewise, you could also say “come over here” in a very harsh tone of voice.

But if you say them both using exactly the same phrasing and tone, “come over here” sounds more like a request, while “get over here” sounds like a demand.

Answer (score 0):

“Get” has a wide field of meaning.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get

Notice meaning 5. When addressing an individual, there is very little difference between “cause to come down” and “come down.” The only difference is that the first stresses the aspect of will and the second stresses the result.

Comment: This is entirely wrong. This is not an example of MW's meaning 5 for **transitive** _get_, but meaning 1 for **intransitive** _get_. Furthermore, in the imperative, this _gt_ is brusque or rude. _Come down_ is neutral_. _Get down_ (in the imperative) is peremptory.

Comment: Well, you are entirely wrong.  Old Brixtonian pointed out that your example is true in a specific context, but is not generally true. “Get here as soon as you can; I can’t wait to see you” is not rude or offensive.